# Background image glitch

Tags: css, safari, background, mobile-safari

I'm banging my head against a wall with a coding problem. I've developed a website with a large background image to allow scrollable content.

The page appears fine on most browsers, but on the ipad/safari, this browser presents the full background image in the viewable area, not just the native resoltion of the background image as per the ther main borwsers.

It's important I keep the image background and allow it to scroll down as some pages on this site will be lengthy. Any ideas would be much apporeicated!

Thanks in advance!

Preview of layout page: http://websiteworkpreview.com/test/index_test.html

The homepage is index.html (for reference) - Homepage uses different bg image. No problems there...!

Error screnshot of background in Safari on iPad: http://websiteworkpreview.com/test/2.JPG

Comment: You can take a screenshot with an iPad by pressing the lock and home buttons at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Safari has had some issues with image filesize, and some known limitations. Take a look at the discussion in the link below. It shows an example that looks very similar to yours, where the image is being cropped vertically, and some specs as to the limitations. Even though it is referencing using an iPhone, it would, of course, affect an iPad as well, as both use Mobile Safari.

http://www.defusion.org.uk/archives/2010/02/19/shrinking-large-background-image-bug-in-iphone-safari/

Comment: Thank you - much appreicated!